# React how to handle OnBlur and 'up' and 'down' arrows are clicked for Input Type is number

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to grab data only when user stops typing and remove cursor from input e.g onBlur along with when Up and down keys are pressed in React

```
var ExampleForm = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {lastName: 1} 
    },
    onsChange: function(event) {
        this.setState({lastName: event.target.value});
    },


    render: function() {
       return (<div>
                <input name='lastName'
                    value={this.state.lastName}
                    type={"number"}
                    onChange={this.onsChange.bind(this)}/>
                  </div>

        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <ExampleForm/>,
    document.getElementById('view'));
```

Comment: You need to bind the "onsChange" to get the data

Comment: @prakash p, I want grab data only when user blur out from input, onChange won't help

Comment: There is an event "onBlur" , it will help you

Answer (score 0):

for remove cursor you have to use setTimeout. **Do like this...**

```js
 onsChange(event) {
        this.setState({lastName: event.target.value});
        var currentTarget = event.target;       
        setTimeout(function(){
            currentTarget.blur();
        }, 3000);
    }
    render() {       
        return (
            <div>
                <input name='lastName'
                    value={this.state.lastName}
                    type={"number"}
                    onChange={this.onsChange.bind(this)}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: you changed the requirement itself my query is to use onBlur with input type number not text, JavaScript is not strongly typed I can assign number to a variable whose value was string.